# How do I get python to only accept positive integer as raw_input?

Tags: python, raw-input

I'm trying to ask the user to submit a positive integer because my question is "How old are you?"

Answer (score 2):

Use [`string.isdigit()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.isdigit).

> str.isdigit()
>
> Return true if all characters in the string are digits and there is at least one character, false otherwise.
>
> For 8-bit strings, this method is locale-dependent.

```
>>> '-23'.isdigit()
False
>>> '23'.isdigit()
True
>>> '23.45'.isdigit()
False
```

So it would be like,

```
>>> while True:
        s = input('How old are you: ')
        if s.isdigit():
            break

    
How old are you: y
How old are you: -7
How old are you: 8.9
How old are you: 8
>>>
```

Comment: And if the user enters +42?